# Mongoid get datetime of a models association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Is possible to get the datetime of an association between two models?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no inbuilt method for it, you have to create a DateTime field in either of the models and save the value when your creating association betweem objects of that models.